# Is there a way to sort the whole database table according to a calculated data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large table called user and it looks like this

| id | events (array) | ... (extra columns) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [] | ... |
| 2 | [] | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

When I query the table, I will pass two extra parameters, no_per_page and page so that only the data I want will be retrieved.

And before returning the data, an extra column called 'total_event_hours' will be calculated using the 'events' column from the query. However, because it is also a column and will be presented in a table of a front-end app, I want it also to be sortable.

The naive way I could think of will be to query the whole table and sort it after the calculation, but since it is very large, it will slow down the process.

Is there a way to sort the table using the calculated column and keep the pagination at the same time? Any input will be appreciated.

Edit:

```
$no_per_page = $param['no_per_page']
$start = $param['page'] > 1 ? ($param['page'] - 1) * $no_per_page : 0;

$query = "SELECT * FROM user LIMIT :start, :no_per_page"; 
$get_query = $this->db->prepare($query);
$get_query->bindParam(':start', $start);
$get_query->bindParam(':no_per_page', $no_per_page);
$get_query->execute();
$data = $get_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $_data) {
  $_data['total_event_hours'] = $this->_getTotalEventHours($_data['events']) 
  // I want to sort by this column but it is not presented in the table
}

return data;
```

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query?  Or is the column not added as part of the query and instead added afterward in the application code?  It's not really clear to me what the problem is.  Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: The column will be calculated after the query is executed. Since it does not exist in the table, ORDER BY does not work.

Comment: If the column isn't part of the query then you can't sort it as part of the query.  *Can* the calculated column be part of the query?  Can you elaborate with a complete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please take a look into the edit

Comment: What does `_getTotalEventHours` do and can that calculation logic be moved to the SQL query itself?  If you can put all of the logic in the SQL query then you can sort on that column in the SQL query.  If you can't then it's not really clear to me what you're asking.  The SQL query can't sort on a column that isn't part of the query.

Comment: ```_getTotalEventHours ``` will loop through every event in the events array, and calculate how long will the event last based on its start and end time. And finally return a integar by adding them together

Comment: Depending on the database you are using, you could create a `GENERATED` column, either virtual or stored one. Then you can index the table by this column. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Mysql

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> Is there a way to sort the table using the calculated column and keep the pagination at the same time?

The DBMS cannot sort data by something it does not know. To sort by a calculated value, there are several possibilities, e. g.

1. sometimes the result of the calculation is in the same order as a column. Then you can sort by this column, of course.
2. you can rewrite your query to include a calculated column. That is, you must perform the calculation with SQL/a user defined function. You can then sort by the calculated column. Note that it's sometimes possible to get the same order with a simpler calculation.
3. approach #2 most likely prevents the DBMS from using an index for sorting. To speed things up, you could modify your table to contain the calculated column, and then update its value using triggers. If you have this column, you can also index it.

As always, there's a trade-off, so it depends on the specific circumstances/use case which option to choose.